# Selecting row in table cause crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Please consider following code:

```
-(void)selectSpecificRowForSpotlight:(NSNumber*)row{
   // dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.1 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        /* Fill news list */

        if (self.singlObj.getSpotlightArray.count > 1){

            if (self.viewModel.arrValues.count > 1){

                NSLog(@"we got spotlight");
                [self.viewModel.arrValues insertObject:[[self.singlObj.spotArray    objectAtIndex:self.singlObj.currentSpotlightIndex-1] objectAtIndex:0] atIndex:0];
                [self.viewModel.arrValues insertObject:[[self.singlObj.spotArray    objectAtIndex:self.singlObj.currentSpotlightIndex-1] objectAtIndex:1] atIndex:1];
                [self.viewModel.arrValues insertObject:[[self.singlObj.spotArray    objectAtIndex:self.singlObj.currentSpotlightIndex-1] objectAtIndex:2] atIndex:2];
            }
        }
         [self.myTableView reloadData];
 });

    NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[row integerValue] inSection:0];
    [self.myTableView.delegate tableView:self.myTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:path];
}
```

Details not really matter, the problem is, following lines:

```
 NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[row integerValue] inSection:0];
    [self.myTableView.delegate tableView:self.myTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:path];
```

cause an crash (SIGABRT error). I fix it with:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.1 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
```

But of course it is not good to call a function by timer, without promise. Why call to delegate method cause crash? How to avoid it without using dispatch_after call?

Comment: @vadian what if i need to select specific row after modify values array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NEVER EVER** call delegate methods starting with or including `will`, `should` and `did` directly. They are called exclusively by the target class.

To select a row there is a method in `UITableView` class

```
- (void)selectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
                    animated:(BOOL)animated
              scrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition
```

Comment: i appreciate your help. When i replace method with     [self.myTableView selectRowAtIndexPath:path animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop];
 it also cause crash. But even when i use dispatch_after and it called, it only select and highlight row (not trigger block in didSelectRowAtIndex:)

Comment: Try to call `selectRow...` on the main thread with `dispatch_async` (not `dispatch_after`!) – maybe also `reloadData`

Comment: It is already on main thread, because of dispatch_get_main_queue(), no?

Comment: Try `dispatch_async` anyway.

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban well, have you tried to add an exception breakpoint? It could point you to a reason of crash, so you could fix the problem instead of finding a workaround.